# How hide/show div based on the drag and drop of an icon

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

Good Morning All,

The goal of my project is to have a drag and drop feature where ... once I drag the icon to the drop box, it displays a div of text that was hidden. So for reiteration - after the icon gets dropped it shows a div that was hidden. The idea was to perhaps call a function that changes the display of the div at the end of the "drop" function body. However, I'm afraid that function never gets called. Perhaps because the "drop" function doesn't get called? I'm not sure .. see some code below.

Also, when I'm running my project .. does javascript & html require that changes displayed on the UI always be via some sort of button/onclick event? Can changes be shown on the UI with simple function calls?

See code below for my first question:
JS code:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=xxxxx=New_York', function(data){
    var display = `${data.location.region}<br>
                   ${data.location.lat}<br>
                   ${data.location.lon}<br>
                   Degree's celcius: ${data.current.temperature}`
    $(".display1").html(display);

  });

  function allowDrop1(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
  
  function drag1(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }
  
  function drop1(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    myFunction1();
  }

  
  function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("display1");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Some html:

```
    <div id = "weatherbox" class="flex-container">
        <div class="display1" style="order: 1"></div>
        <div class="display2" style="order: 2"></div>
        <div class="display3" style="order: 3"></div>    
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div id="div1" class="dropbox" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondrop="myFunction1()" ondragover="allowDrop1(event)"></div>
        <div id="div2" class="dropbox" ondrop="drop2(event)" ondragover="allowDrop2(event)"></div>
        <div id="div3" class="dropbox" ondrop="drop3(event)" ondragover="allowDrop3(event)"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="startbox"><i id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag1(event)" width="336" height="69" class='far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up'></i></div>
        <div class="startbox"><i id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag2(event)" width="336" height="69" class='far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up'></i></div>
        <div class="startbox"><i id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag3(event)" width="336" height="69" class='far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up'></i></div>
    </div>
```

I tried to use event emitter as well to display the div according to the drop of the icon, however I don't think nodejs event emitters are compatible with client side applications.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily there is already an event for this and which is `ondrop`:

```js
drag1.addEventListener('ondrop', function() {
  
  hiddenElt.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Once you drag the icon to the drop box, the hidden item will appear.